# Send alerts to specifically dag owners along with other email alerts or sla - apache airflow

Tags: airflow

In my airflow, I send alerts through slack and email. Email contains a list of emails to send.

Is it possible to send a email specific to dag owner? Putting owner's email in email-list will send lots of other emails that is not wanted.